# Help with Continuing Storm King's Thunder after the campaign is finished

Tags: dnd-5e, storm-kings-thunder

So I'm absolutely new to this site, so I'm sorry if I'm wrong for posting this. I just finished reading Chapter 2 of Storm King's Thunder. And after reading all the side quests and reading a bunch of stuff online, I get the idea that this campaign is pretty much giant sandbox that doesn't actually give you much in what to do to get the players to try to stop the giants, and at the very end the Ordning is still shattered! So I've already been homebrewing a bunch of stuff to throw in with the campaign so at the end they can basically go on this adventure to fix the Ordning. I'm using information pulled from the realms wiki page about deities and such. But I was just trying to figure out if there's a specific campaign that anyone has used or thinks would be best to tie in with SKT to continue afterwards. I was thinking of doing Rise of Tiamat and basically destroy the timeline of things since none of my players are too in tune with that with D&D. I'm also a new DM and feel like I'm probably overthinking everything.

Comment: Welcome to Role-playing Games! Take a look at the [tour]; it's a good introduction to how the site works. Unfortunately brainstorming questions don't work in this site's rigid question-and-answer design. That sort of post works great on a discussion forum though, so we recommend posting these kinds of requests for ideas on one. We have put together [a list of RPG discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449) for this sort of situation; take a look at that list and see if any of those sites suit your needs. Sorry!